# Length of train image dataset and train image loader are different?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

`image_datasets` Is a dictionary containing both train and test data.

Code below:

```
transforms= transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                                transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
```

```
image_datasets = {'train': datasets.CIFAR10(root=data_dir, train=True, download=True, 
                            transform=transforms),
                  'test': datasets.CIFAR10(root=data_dir, train=False, download=True,
                            transform=transforms)
                  }
```

```
image_datasets
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'test': Dataset CIFAR10
     Number of datapoints: 10000
     Root location: ../Data
     Split: Test
     StandardTransform
 Transform: Compose(
                ToTensor()
                Normalize(mean=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), std=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
            ), 'train': Dataset CIFAR10
     Number of datapoints: 50000
     Root location: ../Data
     Split: Train
     StandardTransform
 Transform: Compose(
                ToTensor()
                Normalize(mean=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), std=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
            )}
```

```
#CREATING DATA LOADER 
data_loaders = {
    'train': DataLoader(image_datasets['train'], 10, shuffle=True),
    'test': DataLoader(image_datasets['test'], 10)}
```

When I call `len(data_loaders['train'])` it returns

```
5000
```

When defining my data loader I am using a `batch_size=10`. Is the length of my data_loader being divided by my batch_size. New to coding and just wanted to double check.

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In brief,

- `len(data_loaders['train'].dataset)`gives you how many instances in the dataset e.g., 50000 in CIFAR10.
- `len(data_loaders['train'])` gives you the number of batches in this dataloader e.g., 5000 in CIFA10 if your batch_size=10. Number of batches is calculated by `len(dataset)/(batch_size)`.

Therefore, when we calculate the accuracy in each epoch we divide number of correct ones over `len(data_loaders['train'].dataset)` not `len(data_loaders['train'])` because I fixed this bug in Stack Overflow for someone whose accuracy goes beyond 100% and the cause is division over `len(data_loaders['train'])` .